# How to fix 'Float' object has no attribute 'exp'?

Tags: python, numpy, math, gaussian, algebra

I have the following Gaussian equation in Python:

```
numpy.exp((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma))
```

Provided that `x` is an matrix.

However, the equation won't run, and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT-1**

Making the following edit:

```
map(float(),np.exp((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma)))
```

Raised the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

**EDIT-2**

This is a sample of the value `x`:

```
[[-0.20646505  0.07763347 -0.16161097  0.370439  ]
 [-0.91295327 -0.73768934 -0.78909055  0.06156045]
 [-0.37242104  0.51828245 -1.16138222 -0.02489585]
 [-1.07890926 -0.29704036 -1.7888618  -0.3337744 ]]

m = 5
sigma = 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you do something like `numpy = float()` ??

Comment: If I try to do "np.exp(float((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma)))" or "float(np.exp((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma)))", I get the error: "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: Thats indeed very clear! Only `[1]` can be converted into `1` , not `[1,2,3,4]` , cause python cannot convert list to float. You might use `map(float(),multi_dimensional_array)` to convert every value inside the array to float!

Comment: Thanks so much. Even if I do that, I get "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable". Please see the edits in my question.

Comment: Can you add the sample of the matrix `x` and the values of variables you used?

Comment: Sure, please see the **EDIT-2** in my question

Comment: @Simplicity it might be because you assigned some float to `numpy` reimport it before exectuing the above code of urs.

Comment: Sorry it seems I didn't get your point correct. Can you kindly clarify it a bit?

Comment: What's the ouptut if you call `numpy` it shoud give you
`<module 'numpy' >`. If not something is being assigned to it.

Comment: As others have already said, somewhere in your code you are reassigning a float to `numpy` (ie, `numpy = ...`).

Comment: Try : `map(float,multi_dimensional_array)`

Comment: @Dark Yes, I get: <module 'numpy' from '/Users/xyz/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: Reinstall numpy. You are getting the module and you are getting `AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'exp'`. Hard to tell whats happening

Comment: @UbdusSamad I get "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: Why are you using python 2.7 ?? You should try using python3.x

Comment: @UbdusSamad I think this solved the issue when using Python3. I had another error but is not related to this part of code. Thanks everyone for your kind support.

Comment: Thats very strange behaviour , it should not do that! But again i have seen stranger things!

Comment: Mark your question as answered then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It maybe because you have your array's dtype as object so convert it to float i.e

```
x = np.array([[-0.20646505,  0.07763347, -0.16161097,  0.370439  ],
              [-0.91295327,-0.73768934, -0.78909055,  0.06156045],
              [-0.37242104,  0.51828245, -1.16138222, -0.02489585],
              [-1.07890926, -0.29704036, -1.7888618,  -0.3337744 ]],dtype=object)

m = 5
sigma = 1
np.exp((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma))
```

This will lead to :

```
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Convert it to float i.e:

```
np.exp((-(x.astype(float)-m)**2)/(2*sigma))

array([[  1.29935943e-06,   5.47758566e-06,   1.63950875e-06,
      2.21778276e-05],
   [  2.55786406e-08,   7.10033001e-08,   5.27984133e-08,
      5.06026050e-06],
   [  5.40131118e-07,   4.34936286e-05,   5.70846640e-09,
      3.28945338e-06],
   [  9.45644899e-09,   8.07503629e-07,   9.81698210e-11,
      6.64271640e-07]])
```

This also depends on the numpy version you are using. You should also try updating numpy, so many bugs have been fixed.

Comment: @UbdusSamad what do you mean by that? Did you face any error trying my code.

Comment: Sorry , actually i could not replicate the error he got , so actually i was asking that did you got the same error as the OP did?

Comment: Yes indeed if the dtype is object. It may be because its a old numpy version the OP is using.

Comment: maybe thats why i was unable to replicate the error!

Comment: i think i might have the latest numpy!

Answer (score 0):

```
map(float(),np.exp((-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma)))
```

`map` takes a function and an iterable.  `float` is a function, `float()` is the result of applying that to nothing

```
In [173]: float()
Out[173]: 0.0
```

Hence the complaint that a float is not an callable.  It's not a function.

A proper use of `map` and `float` is:

```
In [175]: list(map(float, [1,2,3]))
Out[175]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

The 2nd argument is the expression which you are already having problems with.  If `x` does not work in the original, it won't work in this call.

`np.exp` applied to an object dtype array, tries to delegate the action to each object of the array.

```
In [174]: np.exp(np.array([[1,2],3,4]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-82d2b5b40b53> in <module>()
----> 1 np.exp(np.array([[1,2],3,4]))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

But most objects don't have an `exp` method.

The key to the original problem is understanding why your `x` is an object dtype array.  Why isn't a float array?  How was it constructed?

The solution in the other answer, which converts the object array to a float array works in this case, but might not with a more general object array.

---

The rest of the `x` expression does work with object dtype array.  In general math on an object dtype array is iffy - working for something, not for others.  It delegates the task to each element, so basic operators like `-` and `**` work.  But even when it works it is slower.

```
In [177]: x =np.random.random((4,2))
In [178]: (-(x-m)**2)/(2*sigma)
Out[178]: 
array([[ -8.07952334,  -8.15537868],
       [-10.37197226, -10.27704074],
       [-11.57978784, -11.18915471],
       [-10.39579226, -10.8018881 ]])
In [179]: (-(x.astype(object)-m)**2)/(2*sigma)
Out[179]: 
array([[-8.079523343837689, -8.155378680249662],
       [-10.371972261358971, -10.277040739722857],
       [-11.579787836524062, -11.189154714963014],
       [-10.395792264129886, -10.80188810039029]], dtype=object)
In [180]: np.exp((-(x.astype(object)-m)**2)/(2*sigma))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-e040a450f8e2> in <module>()
----> 1 np.exp((-(x.astype(object)-m)**2)/(2*sigma))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Answer (score -1):

> Use python 3 instead of 2!

This must be a problem due to anaconda environment or something else the code is right , just use python3.x instead!