# T.Test with two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I have two big dataframes which looks like below:

df

```
            Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal  
gene0       5.0794   1.5045        0   0.5155   5.1258        0   1.7961   2.0333
gene1       88.254  60.9309   2.0367   0.5155  40.5405  21.9554  83.9695   0.4067
gene2        8.254   1.5045   1.0183   1.5464  13.0475   0.9758   2.2452   2.0333
gene3       1.2698   1.5045        0        0        0   0.4879    0.449        0
gene4      860.952  853.785  690.428  609.794  584.809  803.568  845.981  662.464

[139 rows x 113 columns]
```

and df2

```
           Tumor    Tumor    Tumor    Tumor    Tumor    Tumor    Tumor    Tumor  
gene0      16.8883  119.087   4.5331   6.6198   0.8511   1.7598     8.15   6.7992
gene1       7.9272   0.5438  28.1052  98.4692  31.4894   8.7989    4.075  141.213
gene2       2.7573   3.2626  15.4125   9.1022   7.6596   2.3464     6.52    1.569
gene3       3.1019   2.7189   3.6265  12.8258   5.9574   4.1062  163.814  21.4435
gene4      745.497  1387.71  553.944  541.581  448.511  675.172  764.466  850.941

[139 rows x 1101 columns]
```

Anybody knows how to do t-test on between Normal and Tumor dataframes to find out significantly difference gene?

I tried

```
idx = df.index.intersection(df2.index)
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df.loc[idx], df2.loc[idx], axis=1)

error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 75, in <module>
    print(scipy.stats.ttest_ind(Module_1_df_Tumor.loc[idx], Module_1_df_Normal.loc[idx], axis=1))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 4066, in ttest_ind
    df, denom = _equal_var_ttest_denom(v1, n1, v2, n2)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 3884, in _equal_var_ttest_denom
    denom = np.sqrt(svar * (1.0 / n1 + 1.0 / n2))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Thanks

Comment: Your error is not reproducible with your toy data set. And please post the full traceback of your error message.

Comment: Updated the full traceback.

Comment: Do you get the error message with the data you posted here or only with your full set? Do you have [any large numbers in your data set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833893/8881141)?

Comment: The error message is with full set. It contains large numbers upto around 9000.

Comment: Is it because the dataset contains too large number? I can try log normalization on the dataset and check the result again.

Comment: Solve the problem. Quite tricky. Please find:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966728/how-to-fix-float-object-has-no-attribute-exp)

Comment: [It is encouraged to answer your own question and accept it, if you have found a solution to your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)