# why does the error that 'Float' object has no attribute 'dtype' arise?

Tags: python, list, object

I have two nested lists and I want to calculate residues for each element of the two lists.

```
    Coeff_zeros = [(sympy.poly(expand(index_of_zero_e_m[i][1]), s).coeffs()) for i in violates]
    Coeff_zeros_index = list(zip(violates, Coeff_zeros))
```

and

```
    Coeff_poles = [(sympy.poly(expand(index_of_est_pole_m[i][1]), s).coeffs()) for i in violates]

    Coeff_poles_index = list(zip(violates, Coeff_poles))
```

when I used the following code I got the mentioned error:

```
from scipy.signal import residue

Modified_residues = [residue(Coeff_zeros_index[i][1],  Coeff_poles_index[i][1]) for i in violates]
```

BUT, when I copy and paste the result of  `Coeff_zeros_index` and `Coeff_poles_index` inside my code, the same code works without any problem. What's the problem and what should I do? Why printing the result solve the error?
I cannot copy and paste the results of two lists in my code every time.

when I print the `Coeff_poles_index` I'll get :
`Coeff_poles_index = [(0, [1.00000000000000, 5426987090.44496]), (1, [1.00000000000000, 1207636905.04548]), (2, [1.00000000000000, 590484627.473621, 8.12581014483133e+19])]`

and the result of `Coeff_zeros_index` is :
`Coeff_zeros_index = [(0, [1.00000000000000, 80787271317.5307]), (1, [1.00000000000000, 13905630041.1712]), (2, [1.00000000000000, 332812172952.372, 4.17475738734003e+20])`

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: I was just searching SO for almost the exact same problem. Found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966728/how-to-fix-float-object-has-no-attribute-exp which will probably fix your issue here too. In summary: the problem is that your numpy (scipy) array is presumed to have type 'object', and if you explicitly cast it to type 'float' as shown in the link it ought to work. (Posting as a comment, not an answer, because I'm only somewhat sure this is the correct root cause here.)

Comment: @Mr.Snrub It solves the problem, Thanks!